# How to run second azure pipeline on the completion of a stage on first pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to run a different pipeline if one stage is completed on my main pipeline. I tried to do this with stage filters but it didn't work. I have followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops. Is there something else that needs to be done?
[image: stage filters]
[image: code implementation]

Answer (score 3):

The **pipeline** is a custom name you would give to your pipeline to be referenced/used in your YAML file. The **source** is the name of your actual pipeline that was created in Azure DevOps. If you read carefully the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#configure-pipeline-resource-triggers) example, the YAML trigger is defined in the app-ci pipeline to be able to run automatically everytime a new version of security-lib-ci is built.

Example: I want to automatically run my release-pipeline-CD everytime my build pipeline build-pipeline-CI is built.

```
resources:
pipelines:
 - pipeline: CI
   source: 'build-pipeline-CI'
   trigger: true
```